# How do I create search like excel in DataGridView?

Tags: c#, excel, datagridview, find, search-engine

I used this code to search in `DataGridView` to find and select a row (no filter)! But, when `DataGridView` has repetitive values in rows it won't get the next row! How do I go to the next row with every click to `Btn_find` (Find similar to Excel)?

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    button1.Text = "Find Next";

    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
    {
        if (row.Cells["ProductId"].Value == null)
        {
            continue;
        }
        if (row.Cells["ProductId"].Value.ToString().Trim() == textBox1.Text)
        {
            dataGridView1.CurrentCell = row.Cells["ProductId"];
            dataGridView1.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = dataGridView1.Rows[row.Index].Index;
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea:

- Add a private field to the class as an index to remember which row you last found.
- Reset this index if the search text is changed. *(Optional)*
- Iterate through all rows, beginning with the row following the last successful search. If no results were found last search, start at the beginning.

Implementation:

```
private int searchIndex = -1;

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  button1.Text = "Find Next";

  for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
  {
    searchIndex = (searchIndex + 1) % dataGridView1.Rows.Count;
    DataGridViewRow row = dataGridView1.Rows[searchIndex];

    if (row.Cells["Foo"].Value == null)
    {
      continue;
    }
    if (row.Cells["Foo"].Value.ToString().Trim() == textBox1.Text)
    {
      dataGridView1.CurrentCell = row.Cells["Foo"];
      dataGridView1.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = dataGridView1.Rows[row.Index].Index;
      return;
    }
  }
}

private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  searchIndex = -1;
}
```

---

Why these changes?

1. `for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)`

   - Still iterate through every row.
2. `searchIndex = (searchIndex + 1) % dataGridView1.Rows.Count;`

   - Start at row[searchIndex + 1].  When we reach the last row, mod (`%`) returns us to the first row.
3. `private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      searchIndex = -1;
    }`

   - Start back at the beginning of the list when new search criteria are entered.  This is optional.

Comment: How do the results pour in the list box ? ... similar Ecxel Find !

Comment: Do you mean like the `Find All` button in Excel, when it lists all matches in the `Find and Replace` message box beneath the buttons?  That's a separate question, but one I think we could figure out.

Comment: yes ! _Of course without replace_ ... similar this pic : http://s4.picofile.com/file/8187524368/Excel_Search.png

Comment: @ghasemdeh Although this would preferably be a *new* question, I've updated my answer to include the `Find All` functionality.

Comment: hi OhBeWise ... question in : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30136681/how-i-do-create-find-similar-excel