# how i do create find similar excel?

Tags: c#, winforms, find, search-engine

i want create search in form similar EXCEL , find and put (row) in listview
this my form :
[image]

and my code :

```
private int searchIndex = -1;
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        button1.Text = "Find Next";
        try
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                searchIndex = (searchIndex + 1) % dataGridView1.Rows.Count;
                DataGridViewRow row = dataGridView1.Rows[searchIndex];
                if (row.Cells["Product"].Value == null)
                {
                    continue;
                }

                if (row.Cells["Product"].Value.ToString().Trim().StartsWith(textBox1.Text) || row.Cells["Product"].Value.ToString().Trim().Contains(textBox1.Text))
                {
                    ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem(row.Cells["Product"].Value.ToString()); 
                    lvi.SubItems.Add(row.Cells["Product"].Value.ToString());
                    listView1.Items.Add(lvi);
                    dataGridView1.CurrentCell = row.Cells["Product"];
                    dataGridView1.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = dataGridView1.Rows[row.Index].Index;
                    row = dataGridView1.Rows[i];
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
        catch { }
    }
```

and in textbox1_textchanged :

```
searchIndex = -1;
        button1.Text = "Find";
        listView1.Clear();
```

I want when search end, send message ...
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mimicking the `Find All` functionality, populating your `ListView` will be very similar to the `Find Next` functionality.  Here's an example if it were a separate button from `Find Next`:

```
public Form1()
{
  InitializeComponent();
  listView1.View = View.Details;
  listView1.Columns.Add("Column");
  listView1.Columns.Add("Row");
  listView1.Columns.Add("Value");
}

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  button2.Text = "Find All";
  int tempIndex = -1;
  listView1.Items.Clear();

  for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
  {
    tempIndex = (tempIndex + 1) % dataGridView1.Rows.Count;
    DataGridViewRow row = dataGridView1.Rows[tempIndex];

    if (row.Cells["Foo"].Value == null)
    {
      continue;
    }

    if (row.Cells["Foo"].Value.ToString().Trim().StartsWith(textBox1.Text) || row.Cells["Foo"].Value.ToString().Trim().Contains(textBox1.Text))
    {
      DataGridViewCell cell = row.Cells["Foo"];
      ListViewItem lvRow = new ListViewItem(new string[] { cell.ColumnIndex.ToString(), cell.RowIndex.ToString(), cell.Value.ToString() });
      listView1.Items.Add(lvRow);
    }
  }

  MessageBox.Show("Search ended."); // Or whatever message you intend to send.
}
```

[image: Example screenshot.]

Comment: hi, my friend .... this doesn't work !? when press on button ==>> display message Box

Comment: The only way I could reproduce your screenshot was by removing the 3 `listView1.Columns.Add("column name");` calls. Otherwise this code should work, as shown in the screenshot I've edited into my answer. Can you confirm you've added the columns?

Comment: thanks ... that right ... i use in textChanged ==> licstView.Clear();